# Ruby - Deleting every word from an array

Tags: ruby, arrays, string, gsub

In my app, I have to monitor what users type. So I have to prevent any bad words from the web site. Just for example, suppose all my bad words were in this array.

```
bad_words = ['bad', 'evil', 'terrible', 'villain', 'enemy']
```

If a user typed those, I would like them to be deleted. Here was one thing I tried.

```
bad_words.each {|word| string.gsub(word, '')}
```

Help is appreciated.

Comment: change `gsub` to `gsub!` to modify the string object.

Comment: What do you want to do in practice? Do you want to highlight the word when it is typed to warn the writer? Do you want to delete the word when the string is saved?

Comment: A bit more detail for August's comment: gsub() returns a new string, which you don't do anything with, so ruby discards the new string, and the old string remains unchanged.  Ruby has 'bang' forms of a lot of methods, and the bang(!) is a warning that the 'receiver', which is the object calling the method, is going to be altered.

Comment: My goal is to just delete the words from when it's typed. Unless it's in creating a username, I will warn them, by using validates_exclusion of.

Comment: I suggest you change the title from "Deleting every word from an array" to "Deleting certain words from a string".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
bad_words = ['bad', 'evil', 'terrible', 'villain', 'enemy']
orig_str =
  "Evil is embodied by a terrible villain named 'Bad' who plays badmitten"

no_bad_str = orig_str.gsub(/(?<=^|\W)\w+(?=\W|$)/) { |w|
               (bad_words.include?(w.downcase)) ? '' : w }
  #=> " is embodied by a   named '' who plays badmitten"
```

- `(?<=^|\W)` is a positive lookbehind
- `(?=\W|$)` is a positive lookahead

Can bad, evil and terrible words sneak by?  Of course.  Some examples for `orig_str`:

```
badbadbad
evilterribleenemy
eviloff
flyingevil
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

You can use a Gem to do the clean job:

https://github.com/tjackiw/obscenity

including the gem will allow you methods like:

```
Obscenity.configure { |config| config.whitelist = bad_words }
```

and then:

```
Obscenity.sanitize(string)
```

Comment: Awesome, I'll check it out. But usually, language filters are imperfect and easy to bypass. Thanks for the suggestion though

Comment: DarkMouse, what you say is true, but that's also an argument for not rolling your own.

Answer (score 2):

You can either do

```
bad_words.each {|word| string = string.gsub(word, '')}
```

or

```
bad_words.each {|word| string.gsub!(word, '')}
```

Either should work issue with your original was that it was returning a new string not modifying the old one like the to solutions I have proposed above.

Comment: Can't believe I forgot about the bang methods, to modify the original string. Anyways, I decided to use the second option, less code to right, cleaner. Thanks.

Comment: @DarkMouse If you think this is the right answer for you, I suggest you accept it.

Comment: Shane, if you try this with `orig_str` in my answer, the result is  `"Evil is embodied by a   named 'Bad' who plays mitten"`.

Comment: Assigning the return value of gsub() to a variable, and then doing nothing with the variable---does nothing to the original string.

Comment: @7stud, isn't that OK since the variable is `string`, which has already been defined and is being acted upon?

Comment: @7stud In terms of what the OP wants done it will work and just to be clear on what is happening: it over-writes the original object with the new object which was returned by gsub.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Regexp.union`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Regexp.html#method-c-union) to create a regular expression containing all the words in yours list:

```
bad_words = ['bad', 'evil', 'terrible', 'villain', 'enemy']
Regexp.union(bad_words)
# => /bad|evil|terrible|villain|enemy/
string.gsub(Regexp.union(bad_words), '')
```

Comment: Uri, if you run this against `orig_str` in my answer you get `"Evil is embodied in a   named 'Bad' who plays mitten"`.